# LINQ Join Multiple Table Many to Many

Tags: linq

I've Article and ArticleTopics tables.
ArticleTopics Table Storing records TopicId with ArticleId info. 
When trying to retrieve all records that stored with specific TopicId, result returning null even there is at least one record.

```
 public static IEnumerable<ArticleWithVotingInfo> GetArticles(string userId, double time, int Skip, int Take, string sort, int topicId)
{
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId<string>();
    ArticlesDataContext dataContext = new ArticlesDataContext();
    var results = from article in dataContext.Articles
                                    .Where(t => t.DateAdded <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-time))
                  join articleTopics in dataContext.ArticleTopics on article.ArticleId equals articleTopics.ArticleId where articleTopics.TopicId == topicId
                  //where zort.ArticleId == article.ArticleId && zort.TopicId == topicId

                  join h in dataContext.Hosts on article.HostID equals h.HostId
                  join c in dataContext.Categories on article.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId
                  join myvote in dataContext.Votes on article.ArticleId equals myvote.ArticleId into JoinedArticleVote
                  from myvote in JoinedArticleVote.Where(v => v.UserId == userId).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: One: are all inner joins available? Two: use navigation properties instead of joins. Makes it much easier to read and write code.

Comment: thank you for your comment. it was good point to check inner joins. Checked and working good now.